# Why is there a Twist in Odometry message

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Everything basically is in the title. I've been [here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) and I know it's position and speed of the robot. But I'm wondering why you need the speed in the Odometry as it's going to be the exact same thing as the cmd_vel topic.

For example if I'm doing a motor driver taking a Twist as input, should I return the exact same Twist in the /Odometry message afterward ? It seems rather useless to me and I feel like I'm missing something but I don't know what.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141871/why-is-there-a-twist-in-odometry-message/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Twist you send on the "cmd_vel" topic is the **desired** motion you command your robot to perform. The Twist in the [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message you get back is the **measured/estimated** motion that the robot performed. In an ideal world (with perfect controllers and sensing), these would be the same, but that world doesn´t exist ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-19**:
So the driver should be able to return the actual speed of the motor. But wouldn't that be implied by the odometry?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-19**:
In many applications yes, but getting the position of the robot at a given timestamp is only redundant with velocity if the latter doesn´t change between samples.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-19**:
I'm sorry I don't get it. What should not change between samples ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-20**:
If the velocity of the robot does not change over time, the position data is redundant with velocity data (you can get one from the other). If velocity changes over time, it is not redundant, because a given (odometry) position for a timestamp could have been reached with infinitely many velocity profiles. In that  case, the additional Twist information is not redundant.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-20**:
Haaaa I get it ! Thanks a lot for the explanation !